# Number of free parameters in $SU(5)$ GUT model

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, higgs, beyond-the-standard-model, grand-unification

Lately, I have been studying the potential of scalar fields in this theory. In general, what is the point of this GUT if, there, more free parameters have been added?

The standard Higgs potential in the Standard Model with only 2 free parameters (Higgs mass and self-coupling)is
$$V(φ) = \frac{1}{2}m^2φ^2+\frac{λ}{4!}φ^4.$$

For the $SU(5)$ GUT, we have (ignoring possible odd terms),
$$V(Φ,φ) = \frac{1}{2}m_{Φ}^2\operatorname{tr}(Φ^2)+\frac{a}{4!}\operatorname{tr}(Φ^2)^2+\frac{b}{4!}\operatorname{tr}(Φ^4)\\ +\frac{1}{2}m_{φ}^2φ^2+\frac{λ}{4!}φ^4+αφ^\dagger φ\operatorname{tr}(Φ^2)+βφ^\daggerΦ^2 φ,$$
so, in total,  7 free parameters.
I mean, it is clear with the mass and self-coupling of both scalar fields, but why do we need 3 more terms? Are they important?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply the most arbitrary renormalizable, gauge invariant potential for SU(5) with the given field content. The minimization conditions of the potential eliminate some of those arbitrary coefficients in terms of the vacuum expectation values and masses of the Higgses in the 5, and 24 rep.

While you do end up with more freedom here, note that in the fermion sector, the Yukawa couplings to the up and down type quarks as well as the leptons (all united in the 5 and 10 reps) are more constrained, and you have a smaller number of parameters there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no fixed significance to free dimensionless parameters in a theory examined; e.g., *m*, as used in the SM, is not quite a mass, etc.

The GUT action you wrote is the most general *renormalizable* SU(5)-invariant potential given the fields involve, a **24** and a *5*, and the discrete symmetries excluding the odd terms.

See  [here](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Grand_unification#Symmetry_breaking).

Comment: it's a huge fine tuning problem. Can some of those terms be thrown away?

Comment: Yes and no. You could chose not to consider them, but the expectation is that a messy renormalization process would create them as symmetry-allowed effective terms in an effective Lagrangian. Nobody really expects such renormalizable potentials to be there alone and self-standing. It's just that all kinds of irrelevant higher-dimensional terms or an underlying theory *can* engender them. So you'd ignore them at your own risk. At the end of the day, nobody knows anything.

Comment: Remember you are barely 4 orders of magnitude away from the Planck mass. Naturalness?? Angels would fear to tread there….

Comment: what if i am doing non-perturbative calculation and use non-physical mass of 24? I think i can neglect these couplings.

Comment: Which ones specifically? Bursa, Ellis, gaillard and nanopoulos did such in the 70s.

Comment: I mean lattice simulation) These are the ones I want to throw out of potential$$ \frac{b}{4!}tr(Φ^4)+αφ^\dagger φ\operatorname{tr}(Φ^2)+βφ^\daggerΦ^2φ $$

Comment: It’s a start…  .

Comment: What? Didn't understand you

Comment: If it did the [job](https://doi.org/10.1016/0550-3213(78)90214-6)… SSB.

Comment: Yes, it did. It just requires tuning of m^2 and lambda. Don't get me wrong, I just don't want to include too many couplings because it's very computationally expensive to tune all of them.

Comment: You may address this particular case first and then contemplate the effect of including other terms, in principle.

Comment: Can you explain why $btr(Φ^4)$ has a normalization factor of 4, but these couplings don't have it $αφ^†φtr(Φ^2) + βφ^†Φ^2φ $

Comment: It is a peculiar convention of your undisclosed source. You notice Langacker (13) in my link uses other ones, BEGN in (4.2), etc.... It depends what will give you simpler expressions in the SSB process, which, as you may have noticed, can be organized very  variously...

Comment: This convention i found in this dissertation while searching the internet, https://fenix.tecnico.ulisboa.pt/downloadFile/395143154268/Thesis.pdf

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140764/discussion-between-cosmas-zachos-and-peter).